# How do I do an HTTP redirect in Java like res.redirect() in ExpressJS?

Tags: java, http, server, redirect

I am building a Java web framework (for fun; I am not trying to "reinvent the wheel") and I want to have a redirect method like that of `res.redirect('/myUrl')` in ExpressJS. How can I do so using only the standard Java net packages (`java.net` and  `java.io`)? The method simply needs to take a string (but taking more info, such as a request object, is also fine) and redirect a user's request to the specified url with a `302` code.

Comment: Are you running any kind of Web framework? How are you processing the incoming command? To do the redirect, you will need to respond to the HTTP request with a 302 or something. I suggest you look into using Spring Framework, or Jetty for running the webserver.

Comment: I am trying to build my own framework as a project to gain Java skills, so I am, of course, not using a framework (please don't tell me that a premade framework would be easier; again, I am trying to learn Java and improve my skills by doing thinking myself). I am using the java.net and java.io library to accept connection sockets in a while loop.